# return array instead of objects laravel/javascript ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5, vuejs2

I am creating a front-end Vue component. For this I am using data and a database from a Laravel project. The problem I got is that a method from Laravel (And so does the AJAX call) is returning an Array, which is good, and the other method is returning just the objects (collection?) with the AJAX call. I need both calls returning an Array because I am using some Array functions in my component.

I've tried all sort of things, both on the front-end as back-end. I've tried on the backend to let laravel return an array and on the Front-end I tried to set the objects to an array. Both didn't succeed.

My JS code (And AJAX calls)

```
    methods: {

        countAllItems() {
            this.countItems = this.items.length;
        },

        getUrl(items) {

            let results = items;

            results.forEach((item) => {

                let id = item.id;

                return item.url = `/advertisements/show/${id}`;
            });

        },

        getMax(items) {

            let boats = items.slice(0, 4);

            this.items = boats;

            this.getUrl(this.items);
            this.countAllItems();

        },

        getBoats() {

            axios.get('/api/boats')
                .then((response) => {

                    //this will return an array
                    console.log(response.data);
                    this.items = response.data;

                    this.countAllItems();
                    this.getMax(this.items);




                })
                .catch((error) => console.log(error));

        },

        getReservations() {

            axios.get('/api/popular')
                .then((response) => {

                    //this will return objects, and must be an array
                    console.log(response.data);
                    this.items = response.data;

                    this.countAllItems();
                    this.getMax(this.items);

                });
        }

    },

    created() {
        this.getBoats();
        this.getReservations();
    }
```

The back-end

```
//This will return the array
public function boats() {

    return Boat::with('media')->get();

}

//This will return objects
public function messages() {

    $boats = Boat::with('media')->get()->sortByDesc(function($boat) {
        return count($boat->conversations);
    });

    return $boats;

}
```

[image: console.logs]

Is there someone who can help me out? So I need either a fix for returning an array in the Laravel method, or something like a function to push both objects to an array in JavaScript.

**Edit**

So I tried some things and doing that something occured to me. When I do `dd($boats)` it will return a Collection. When I do `dd($boats->toArray)` it returns an array. What the weird thing is is that it makes no difference tho in the AJAX calls. So `$boats->toArray()` will still return only the objects and not the objects in an array.

I also tried to push the objects in an array but that doesn't work either. It will place the collection (as a object) into an array. How can I change this that the objects will directly be inserted in the array instead of the collection as a object?

```
let arr = [];

arr.push(response.data);

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: use toArray(); function

Comment: Like this `return $boats->toArray();`? Because I already tried that and that doesn't work.

Comment: yes, what is the output

Comment: read this one also https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-serialization

Comment: @CasperSL Exactly the same in the AJAX call.

Comment: So I tried to `dd` the data and what supprised me is that the `toArray()` function is returning an array in the dump but the AJAX call is still returning just the objects.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159558/discussion-between-caspersl-and-gijsberts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think problem with collection manipulation, When you do collection manipulation, it changes the values.

```
public function messages() { 
  $boats = Boat::with('media')->get(); 
  $sorted = $boats->sortByDesc('do your sort here'); 

  return $sorted->values(); 
}
```